# Creating Microsoft OnPremise User with Azure RunBook

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-runbook, hybrid-runbook-worker

we are extensively using services in the Azure Cloud, but our On-Premise Active Directory is not yet fully migrated. Currently, the synchronization of the On-Premise AD only occurs in one direction, from Entra to On-Premise AD. However, operations in reverse, such as creating users in EntraID, work but are not synchronized with the On-Premise AD.

Currently, we are faced with the challenge of using a web application to create users. The workflow is intended to be as follows:

```
The backend receives a list of users from the HR system.
The backend verifies the list.
If there are users in the list that do not exist yet, they should be created.
```

In Step 3, we encounter the issue that we cannot use the Graph API. I've seen that there are RunBooks, but I'm not entirely sure how they can help me achieve this goal. As per my understanding, I would create a RunBook that I trigger with a WebHook.

In the WebHook's body, I would include the user data that needs to be created. However, at the moment, I'm unsure of how the RunBook would then connect to the On-Premise AD and proceed to create the users.

I would appreciate your assistance and suggestions on how to efficiently and resource-effectively implement this integration. Thank you in advance!

1. Created a RunBook
2. Tested WebHook to Call the RunBook
3. Dont have a clue, how to connect to on premise ad

Comment: Have you tried any code so far? @Pointless

Comment: Assuming your end goal is to create users in on-premise AD from HR system, have you explored API-driven provisioning" feature - Using API-driven provisioning create/update on-premises AD users and Sync on-premises AD users to the Entra ID tenant using Cloud Sync or Connect Sync. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/app-provisioning/inbound-provisioning-api-concepts
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/app-provisioning/inbound-provisioning-api-configure-app

Comment: I tried a hybrid worker with runbook and webhook and i could create a directory on the machine (huge win). So now i have to check if i can create users in the ad. When this works, i describe it as solution.

Comment: Our local AD is only syncing to Entra but not the other way arround. Thats the problem. If the EntraId would sync to the local AD, i would use the GraphAPI @Givary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have devised a solution.

Firstly, I established an automation account and crafted a runbook for generating Active Directory users, along with a webhook to facilitate user data transmission. Subsequently, I configured a hybrid worker group and integrated the virtual machine with the local Active Directory.

Within the interface of the runbook and webhook, I designated the hybrid worker group (comprising the single VM) and initiated several POST requests using Insomnia.